# How to convert jQuery carousel into React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, gatsby

So I am trying to take this flex-box carousel method of jQuery and convert it into React for Gatsby, but I'll admit I'm new to both Gatsby and React. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Here is a link of reference for the jQuery method: https://codepen.io/veronicadev/pen/yjgjvL

Is there an easier method to have a carousel work in Gatsby? Because I tried to install with react-carousel before and it didn't seem to quite work.

```
class Products extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            isActive : false,
            total : $('.carousel-item').length,
            current : 0,
        }
    }

    toggleActive = () => {
      this.state({
        isActive: !this.state.isActive,
      })
    }
    slideRight = () => {
        this.state({
            next = current,
            current = current + 1,
            setSlide(next,current) { 
                this.state({
                    slide = current,
                    if (next > total-1) = {
                      slide = 0
                      current = 0 
                    }, if (next < '0') {
                        slide = total-1,
                        current = total + 1, 
                    },
                    $('.carousel-item').onClick(toggleActive);
                })
        },
    }),
    }
    slideLeft = () => {
        this.state({
            prev = current,
            current = current - 1,
            setSlide(prev, current)

                })
            }
        })
    }

    render (){
    return (
    <div className="product-body">
        <div className="carousel">
        <div className="carousel__nav">
        <span id="moveLeft" className="carousel__arrow" onClick={this.slideLeft}>
        <svg className="carousel__icon" width="15" height="26" viewBox="0 0 15 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M12.8507 24.0657L2 13.215L12.8507 2.36432" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </svg>
            </span>
            <span id="moveRight" className="carousel__arrow" onClick={this.slideRight}>
            <svg className="carousel__icon" width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M13.4109 3.00001L24.0779 14.0312L13.0467 24.6983" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div className="pages">
                    <GreenBackground
                    className={`carousel-item--01 ${isActive}`}
                    id="greenbck"
                    itemImage = {imageList.turdBurgler}
                    price="$5.00"
                    title="Turd Burgler"
                    category="stranger"
                    calories="789 calories"
                    description="Two chocolate cake donuts smothered in cookie butter glaze. Oreo chocolate chip cookie dough. With fudge drizzle."
                    />
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    )
                }
}
export default Products;
```

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery in react ?

Comment: I suggest you to forget using jQuery inside your react application. This carousel just needs one event handler and some simple states. I recommend you to take a look at https://reactjsexample.com/tag/carousel/.

If you are insisting  using jQuery visit: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html