# The carousel is not working and getting $('carouselId').carousel is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, carousel

I am creating a nextJS app and I am creating a carousel component and trying to use it in index.js

Below is the code of my component and I am using the code that's used at https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8/bootstrap-carousel-with-multiple-cards.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Container, Row, Card, Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import styles from './NewsAndEvents.module.css';

const NewsAndEventsComponent = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    setIndex(selectedIndex);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Fired', $('#recipeCarousel'));
    $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000,
    });

    $('#recipeCarousel.carousel .carousel-item').each(function () {
      var minPerSlide = 3;
      var next = $(this).next();
      console.log(next);
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.mainDiv}>
      <Container>
        <Row className={styles.newEventsHeaderContainer}>
          <p className={styles.mainText}>News and Events</p>
          <Pagination className={styles.mainText}>
            <Pagination.Prev className={styles.paginationButton} />
            <Pagination.Next className={styles.paginationButton} />
          </Pagination>
        </Row>
        <div className="container text-center my-3">
          <div className="row mx-auto my-auto">
            <div
              id="recipeCarousel"
              className="carousel slide w-100"
              data-ride="carousel"
            >
              <div className="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=1"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=2"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=3"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=4"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=5"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="carousel-item active">
                  <div className="col-md-4">
                    <div className="card card-body">
                      <img
                        className="img-fluid"
                        src="http://placehold.it/380?text=6"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a
                className="carousel-control-prev w-auto"
                href="#recipeCarousel"
                role="button"
                data-slide="prev"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a
                className="carousel-control-next w-auto"
                href="#recipeCarousel"
                role="button"
                data-slide="next"
              >
                <span
                  className="carousel-control-next-icon bg-dark border border-dark rounded-circle"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
export default NewsAndEventsComponent;
```

I am getting the below error while trying to execute the $('#recipeCarousel').carousel({interval: 5000,}); inside useEffect.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what i might be missing or maybe doing incorrectly? Please advise

Ps- Have imported below line in the _app.js file as well.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Consider not mixing jQuery and React, since they will likely conflict with each other?

Comment: Does this answer your question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138419/how-to-convert-jquery-carousel-into-react

Comment: @mutantkeyboard didn't work

Comment: Any idea on how to convert https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8/bootstrap-carousel-with-multiple-cards to React??

Comment: I don't want to sound defeatist, but it's probably best to look for something else that's built using react.